# .htaccess file ignored on Ubuntu server

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu

I have recently moved to a new server for my website, and i activated mod_rewrite with success, but some files still not working !

Like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^activate\/(.*)\/(.*)$  activate.php?Email=$1&hash=$2
```

I have made all necessary changes on my VPS (Ubuntu) !

Any idea ?

**Like this lines work well:**

```
RewriteRule ^search\/(.*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  search.php?view=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^search$  searchResults.php
RewriteRule ^term$  term.php
RewriteRule ^faq$  faq.php
# Non-working line...
RewriteRule ^activate\/(.*)\/(.*)$  activate.php?Email=$1&hash=$2
```

Note that mod_rewrite are enabled and all other lines work well only this one !

Comment: What other lines work well? Please always post the entire contents of .htaccess because it is highly order-dependent.

Comment: `not working` could you be more explicit ?

Comment: Please edit above to include all rewrite rules in their correct order, and also post specific example URLs you are using to test (both working and non-working)

Comment: Ok, you've added some - but please place the non-working line in correct context of the others. (does it come before, after, middle?).  We need to see it in order with the others.

Comment: I reordered them :) please check :)

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteBase` ?

Comment: Yes :) but problem solved that you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you **must** define a `RewriteBase` because of your two rules (first and last) that create both virtual directories.

Then, you should disable `MultiViews` option to make `term` or `faq` rule work without problem.

Finally, you can rewrite your patterns in a more generic way (or at least in a better way, more precise). Also, don't forget `L` flag (`[L]`) after each rule, otherwise *mod_rewrite* continues to evaluate next rules.

You can replace your current code in your htaccess by this one (assuming your htaccess is in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?view=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ searchResults.php [L]
RewriteRule ^term$ term.php [L]
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^activate/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ activate.php?Email=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I love you, you solved my problem :) in my case i had `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the first, i modified it to `Options -MultiViews` and solved it :) but will take your advices and make big changes on it :) thank you ...